# How to a send a specific text backside to print in a paper using C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, printers

Hope all are safe!!

Currently I read a HTML file and send to printer based on it, in my C# code.
So it will print the desired format front side of the paper/card.
Now as per the requirement I need to send a specific text to print on the backside of the paper/card.

Is there some way to manipulate and send the text from C# code so that it prints backside of the paper/card.

Say eg., I print "Thanks in advance" text from the html file I have in the front side of the paper and I need to print "Thank you for the time" text to print on the backside.

Can someone help me to find a way?!

Comment: The printer has to support duplex (double-sided) printing for this to have any hope of working in the first place.

Comment: Does it only have to work on *one* brand/make/model of printers?  Please identify  which one.

Comment: This is entirely determined by the printer driver; it has nothing to do with C#, HTML, or .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can send text data to the printer but can not decide whether to print on the front or back side of the page. This is done by the printer itself normally printer print data on front side of paper you need to set printer setting to print back side of paper too.

Or you need to build a app [using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printdialog-in-C-Sharp/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20step%20is%20to,snippet%20creates%20a%20PrintDialog%20control.&text=PrintDocument%20object%20represents%20a%20document,of%20PrintDialog%20as%20this%20document.) that have functionality to control your printer's printing behaviour.